# How do you speak to a Blade in an inn?

Tags: xenoblade-chronicles-2

I have a bunch of quests that require me to speak to a particular Blade in a specific inn. I go there and don't see any heart to hearts. I have tried resting and making them my active blade to no avail. How do I talk to one of my specific Blades?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sleep at the inn and the next morning the plot will trigger.

Comment: I thought I tried that, but I'll try again. Does long or short rest matter?

Comment: Short rest is enough.  Blade will tell you, where HtH is placed.

Comment: @lentinant I just came here to comment that myself. Another thing for anyone who might not get it: you might have multiple events that can be chosen from. Keep resting until you get it. Turns out I had quite a queue of heart to hearts waiting for me.

Comment: @Seiyria: I'm stuck on Pyra's level 3 Purifying Flames, which appears to be a "talk to her at Connie's house" from what I've read. Even while in Tantal, I was unable to get this to trigger. Should I just sleep there more or something?